# Get the result type of a function in c++11

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, type-traits

Consider the following function in C++11:

```
template<class Function, class... Args, typename ReturnType = /*SOMETHING*/> 
inline ReturnType apply(Function&& f, const Args&... args);
```

I want `ReturnType` to be equal to the result type of `f(args...)`
What do I have to write instead of `/*SOMETHING*/` ?

Comment: Wouldn't `decltype(f(args...))` do it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you should rewrite your function template using **trailing-return-type** as:

```
template<class Function, class... Args> 
inline auto apply(Function&& f, const Args&... args) -> decltype(f(args...))
{
    typedef decltype(f(args...)) ReturnType;

    //your code; you can use the above typedef.
}
```

Note that if you pass `args` as `Args&&...` instead of  `const Args&...`, then it is better to use `std::forward` in `f` as:

```
decltype(f(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
```

When you use `const Args&...`, then `std::forward` doesn't make much sense (at least to me).

It is better to pass `args` as `Args&&...` called *universal-reference* and use `std::forward` with it.

Comment: Is it better to pass the arguments as universal references or as constant references ?

Comment: @Vincent: Universal references. That is better.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't need to be a template parameter, since it isn't used for overload resolution.  Try

```
template<class Function, class... Args> 
inline auto apply(Function&& f, const Args&... args) -> decltype(f(std::forward<const Args &>(args)...));
```

Comment: What is the difference between a version with and whithout std::forward ?

Comment: He is passing `Args` by `const &`. So does it much make sense to use `std::forward`?

Comment: @Nawaz: Maybe not, but I suspect it should actually be `Args&& ...args`.  However that's a different question.  I just want this answer to be robust in the face of such changes.

Comment: @Vincent: The difference is that this doesn't break if you decide to use perfect forwarding in the future.

Comment: Does this even work? The way I see it `std::forward<Args>(args)` would cast `args` from `const Args&` to `Args&&` (note that I talk about single elements of the pack of ease of expression), meaning it would remove the constness (if it even works, which it shouldn't, since `forward<T>` should take either `T&` or `T&&`, but not `const T&`).

Comment: @Grizzly It is indeed incorrect to forward that way, but `std::forward` *has* to be able to deal with const-qualified types since an argument of the style `T&&` can (thankfully) deduce to `T == U const` or `T == U const&` -- in which cases `std::forward<T>` has result type `U const&&` and `U const&` respectively. So this answer would benefit from using `std::forward<Args const&>`, although this would still be sillier than not forwarding at all.

Comment: @LucDanton: I never meant to imply that `std::forward` can't deal with `const` arguments at all, just that it can't do so if its template-argument is a non const type.

Answer (score 0):

There are situations where **std::result_of** is more useful. For example, say you want to pass this function:

```
int ff(int& out, int in);
```

and inside apply() call it like so

```
int res;
f(res, args...);
```

then I wouldn't know how to use decltype, because I have no int lvalue reference at hand. With result_of, you don't need variables:

```
template<class Function, class... Args> 
typename std::result_of<Function(const Args&...)>::type apply(Function&& f, const Args&... args)
{
  typedef typename std::result_of<F(const Args&...)>::type ReturnType;

  // your code
}
```