# Is it possible to use function return type as an argument in declaration of another function in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

I want something like this:

```
std::tuple<int, bool, double> MyFunction_1 (void);

void MyFunction_2 (decltype (MyFunction_1) &params);
```

Obviously, in this example a code pointer to function would be passed.

I want to have the equivalent of this:

```
void MyFunction_2 (std::tuple<int, bool, double>  &params);
```

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: About wording, I think you are asking if it is possible to use MyFunction_1 **return type** as an **argument** for MyFunction_2

Comment: Yup. Thanks for correction

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the result type of a function in c++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14144573/get-the-result-type-of-a-function-in-c11)

Comment: no its not a duplicate because my question is worded in a different and more clear way

Answer (score 35):

`decltype (MyFunction_1)` will give you the type of `MyFunction_1` (i.e. the function type `std::tuple<int, bool, double> ()`), you need to *emulate a function calling* <sup>1</sup> (via adding `()`) to get the return type (i.e. `std::tuple<int, bool, double>`), e.g.

```
void MyFunction_2 (decltype (MyFunction_1()) &params);
//                                       ^^
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> The expression is evaluated at compile-time, the function won't be called at run-time actually.</sup>

Comment: Because....? FGITWing is nice and all, but an answer should explain to the OP and future readers *why* adding two characters solves the problem here.

Comment: Would "you need to emulate a function call in the `decltype()`" be a better wording? :P

Comment: Another approach (maybe more straightforward): [std::result_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of)

Comment: @Ptaq666 That's an answer and should be posted as one.

Answer (score 16):

The *type* of `MyFunction_1` is not `std::tuple<int, bool, double>` - informally you can think of it as a function pointer. In fact `&MyFunction_1` *decays* to itself and is *certainly* a pointer.

So `decltype(MyFunction_1)` is not what you want.

The solution is to write `decltype(MyFunction_1())`. The *type* of `MyFunction_1()` *is* `std::tuple<int, bool, double>`. Note that this doesn't actually *call* the function; it's rather like `sizeof` in that respect.

Comment: `MyFunction_1` decays to a pointer, `&MyFunction_1` does not -- it is one already :)

Answer (score 3):

```
using RetType = std::invoke_result<decltype(f)>::type;
```

Play with it : https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/AE7lj_